# Call to arms to grapple with unanswered questions

Tags: discussion, unanswered

Currently we have [24 questions with no answers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers) and another three with answers that have not been upvoted.

This is a pretty small percentage of the 650 questions that have been asked so far on the site, but it seems a pity to leave them unanswered if someone can work out a solution.

Comment: Need to leave some fodder for Necromancer badges...

Comment: Yes, but @Brett do we want all those zombie questions roaming about? They tend to leave nasty stains on the carpeting and furniture. Not to mention that whole brain eating issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

24 unanswered questions is not bad. But, I see your point that we do not want it to get bad. Towards that end, I would suggest we do something similar to what [tex.se](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) has been doing: [holding regular chat meetings to deal with the unanswered questions](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1560/1004).  Since we do not have the influx of questions they do, this can be more of an irregular occurrence for us, and could become regular, if needed.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that, in the long run, having some unanswered questions is a good thing.  The most successful SE sites seem to hover around 80-85% answered.  If all (or very nearly all) the questions are answered, then a new expert wandering by has nothing to do, whereas if there are unanswered questions, a new expert wandering by might get sucked in by one of those, perhaps answering it or perhaps not, but hanging around long enough to see when a new, more answerable question is posted.

Comment: You bring up a good point.  Also, maybe it's better not to force giving an only semi-helpful answer on a question that could get a better answer when an expert in the field comes along.  I received a [good answer on one of my question on math](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/82072/12384) only a full month after I have posted it, despite the bounty I set (which did attract a not too helpful attempt).

Answer (score 2):

These are practically resolved, even though they don't have a formal answer:

- [How to work with characters from CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B correctly?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/215/how-to-work-with-characters-from-cjk-unified-ideographs-extension-b-correctly)
- [Visual Studio Express 2010 on x86-64: libcmt.lib missing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2010/visual-studio-express-2010-on-x86-64-libcmt-lib-missing)

These are pretty much duplicates of each other (looking at the posters' intentions):

- [How to manipulate web pages on Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2362/how-to-manipulate-web-pages-on-mathematica)
- [Web Browsing Automation with Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1775/web-browsing-automation-with-mathematica)

I expect the solution to this to do more with maths than Mathematica (didn't have time to read up on it in detail yet):

- <strike>[How to plot planar graphs as such?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1781/how-to-plot-planar-graphs-as-such)</strike>  (I just got an answer to this, but it's not exactly the answer I need (though it's cool)).

Also, many questions require clarification from the askers to proceed.